# Chrome doesn't show background on rounded img

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, chromium

I'm trying to implement this:
[image]

Which consists of a green dotted image and a rounded `img` tag.
Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzrje625/).

Html:

```html
<div class="img-dot-wrapper">
  <img class="round" src="http://up.0se.ir/uploads/60fffaaf304346f175610c1a96fc99f770784c76.png">
</div>
```

Css:

```css
.round {
  border-radius: 200px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.img-dot-wrapper {
  background-image: url("http://up.0se.ir/uploads/38d9365a30559bb58eb729a5955b3987185f83ad.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This works fine in FF, however, in chrome based browsers it doesn't show the green dotted image.

If I add a margin (even 1px) to `img` tag, the green dotted image will be shown!

I suspect this is an optimization bug in rendering the overlapped images but not sure. Do you think It's a bug?

Comment: I have tested your `jsfiddle` on chrome browser and it works with no issues.

Comment: you can add background-size:contain; or remove backgroun-repeat and instead add float:left i can see the problem somtimes it shows and then disappear

Comment: Its working fine in Google Chrome no issue :)

Comment: @Derek.W It doesn't work in chrome mobile too!

Comment: its disappearing on background no repeat change it to repeat-y or as i comented before

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you running? And on what platform (desktop / mobile / ipad ,etc.)?